# php - secure access to file

Tags: php, iphone, web-services

I have an iphone application that gets data from a set of php files.
The php files return XML based on the query string parameters.
What would be the best way to secure and restrict access to these "web services"?

Thank you!

**Edit:** The server is running CentOS/Apache and I would like to limit access so that only the application will be able to access the files. I don't want the files to be accessible from outside of the application. (The application will be ported to android and blackberry as well).

Comment: Even if I knew the details that could help me give you an approximate answer, such as the webserver you are using the type of lockdown you want (IE: just iphones? just one iphone? ) -> With all the possible answers this question has,  I don't think there is a "best" way.

Comment: @stefgosselin - edited the post with some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a hash in your iPhone application that gets passed along with the other query strain parameters. The hash should include a "key" (or "shared secret") that's only known by the web server and the iPhone application as well as one or more of the query string parameters that are passed.

The PHP script that will receive the information can then regenerate the hash since it knows the "key". If the "key" matches the one in the query string, the request is valid and came from an iPhone, otherwise it didn't.

**Update**: To prevent someone from using the same query string to request the same information over and over again, you can add an "expiry" timestamp to the query string and hash and check that the request hasn't expired if the hash is valid.

I can't provide an Objective-C but your PHP script could look like this:

```
<?php

$hash = md5('SHAREDSECRET'.$_REQUEST['expiry'].$_REQUEST['param1'].$_REQUEST['param2']);

if ( $hash != $_REQUEST['$hash'] || time() > $_REQUEST['expiry'] )
  die('Invalid request.');

// Some additional code here for valid requests.

?>
```

Based on the example above, you'd want the iPhone application to create an MD5 hash of the shared secret ("SHAREDSECRET" in this case), "param1", and "param2" and include it in the request to the PHP file.

The URL that the iPhone requests should look like this:

```
http://example.org/file.php?hash=value&expiry=timestamp&param1=value&param2=value
```

Of course the "key" itself wouldn't be passed in the query string making it difficult for someone to figure out how to get to your information (unless it through the iPhone app of course).

Comment: Same comment as above. Can't someone just check on the query string and use the string after hashing?

Comment: @Elad Lachmi - If you mean would they use the same hash over and over again to retrieve the same information? Yes they could. But to circumvent that problem, you could include an "expiry" parameter (i.e. current time + 1 minute) in your query string as well as in the hash calculation and make sure that the request isn't expired if it's valid at the other end.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi - By using a solution such as the one I'm suggesting, you're not relying on the user agent string which means that it'll definitely work on iPhone, Blackberry and Android devices.

Comment: Just to check that I understand what you are suggesting: The timestamp is added to the hash so that even if the hash is used again, it will not be valid?

Comment: Seems like a solid solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, you can check if the user-agent matches that of the iphone.

In our case, we compute a hash of a static query param(or path string) combined with a salt and send that as an extra query param. We do the same check on the PHP side to ensure whether the hash is the same. This can be used for any client, but you could have different salt values for each client that talks to your PHP service.

Comment: Can't someone just look at the request and mimic the hashed string from outside of the application?

Comment: Yeah, thats possible but you could just use one of your existing query params to provide more randomness, but if the request is snooped and sent as is, then it cant be prevented. Would doing a user agent check (although it can be faked) in addition to the above help?

Comment: If the request is snooped and sent as is, it can be prevented. See my answer.

Comment: Nice example of _insecure security_. [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is not considered a security measure, and should not be used as such.